# Trouble with .getTime()

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to HTML and Javascript, so I'm trying to make a small incremental game as practice. This is the code I am trying to use to calculate the automatic gains / second, as well as adjust accordingly for when the tab isn't in focus and `setInterval` stops running.

```
var startTime = new Date();
var endTime = new Date();
var interval = 100;


window.setInterval(function(){
startTime.getTime();
var timeDiff = startTime - endTime;

do{
document.getElementById('woodAmount').innerHTML =  Math.floor(user.wood += (user.WPS/10));
document.getElementById('oilAmount').innerHTML =  Math.floor(user.oil += (user.OPS/10)); 
document.getElementById('goldAmount').innerHTML =  Math.floor(user.gold += (user.GPS/10));
document.getElementById('coalAmount').innerHTML = Math.floor(user.coal += (user.CPS/10));
timeDiff -= interval;
}while (timeDiff >= interval);

endTime.getTime();
}, interval);
```

For some reason, this code doesn't adjust for the time when the tab is not focused, but it works as expected when it is in focus.
 
As you can see here, I set the `interval` to 100 milliseconds, and I divide the resources / second (`user.WPS`) by 10.

However, when I set the `interval` to 1 second (1000 milliseconds) and *don't* divide the resources / second by 10, it works as expected all the time, and properly adjusts for the time that the tab isn't focused.
Can anyone offer an explanation as to why it works when using full-second intervals, but won't when using 100 millisecond intervals?

Comment: The line `startTime.getTime();` does nothing at all. It calls the `.getTime()` function and then throws away the returned value.

Comment: The code works, however, when `interval = 1000` and `user.WPS` isn't divided by anything. If `startTime.getTime();` didn't work, shouldn't the code fail to work in both scenarios?

Comment: No; it's not an *error*, it's just pointless. It's not clear what you expect that statement to do.

Comment: My intention was to use the values of `startTime` and `endTime` to calculate how long `setInterval` is paused for and adjust for that length of time. Are you saying that I would need to put them into separate variables before using them?

Comment: What I'm saying is that calling `someDate.getTime()` has absolutely no effect on the value of `someDate`.  It's a function that *returns* something, not a function that *modifies* the value of the Date object.

Comment: I understand. I managed to fix my issue by using `var startTime = Date.now()` instead of using `startTime.getTime();` in the way I had it set up previously. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.getTime()` gets the time that is already in the `Date` object at the time it was created or whenever the time was last set in the date object.  It does NOT get the current time.

If you want to get the current time, I often use this little function:

```
function now() {
   return new Date().getTime();
}
```

Or, if you don't need IE8 support, then you can use `Date.now()`.

In addition, the `getTime()` method pulls the time out of the data object and returns it from that method call.  If you want to use it, you have to put it somewhere after calling `.getTime()`.

Comment: +1 I personally depend on `Date.now` for a lot of things

Comment: @naomik - `Date.now()` requires IE9 or a polyfill.  If you can give up IE8 support or are willing to install a polyfill, then it works just fine.

Comment: I change my code so instead of using `startTime = new Date();` and `startTime.getTime();`, I used `var startTime = Date.now();` and it works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @jfriend00, thanks for the notice about IE8. I live life without regrets, so I almost completely forgot about it ^.^